# Is it possiable to have the detailTextLabel automaticly resize the font?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the *UITableViewCellStyleValue1* for my table cell style. That's the one that puts the textLabel on the left, left aligned, and the detailTextLabel on the right, right aligned.

Some of the data I'm passing to the cell, at times, is to long for the label and I get the the truncated look with the ... at the end.

I think it would look better if it would just lower the point size of the font to make it fit.

Is there a way to do this automaticly or would I have to manualing check the length and modifying the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you run into a limitation with Apple's default cell styles, which can be often,  make your own `UITableViewCell` subclass and add custom views to its `contentView` property.

Comment: That's also my thinking, but I just didn't know if their was any "short cut" already built in. Wishful thinking on my part. Thanks